# Turn LED on/ off when inserting a record into a MySQL database on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, led

I am trying to switch on an LED whenever a record is inserted into a MySQL database.

Currently I am using a Trigger with the MySQL UDF sys_exec() to run a python script, which all works fine, unless i want to turn on a GPIO pin.

Below are 2 python scripts (both identical except for one has the GPIO setup and GPIO output lines commented out).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

pin = 21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.25)
GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

This script will run fine when executed from the python Shell, but fails when the trigger executes it, and sys_exec will return 256 (which I believe means it's false?)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

pin = 21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

# GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.25)
# GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

This one runs fine from the trigger.

Here is the code for my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trig
AFTER INSERT ON LED_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
        DECLARE result int(10);
        SET cmd = ('python /home/pi/test.py');
        SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Does anyone know as to why when I try and activate the GPIO pins from the trigger it will fail?

EDIT:

So the issue was caused by the mysql user not having permissions to use the GPIO pins. I resolved this by adding the mysql user to the gpio user group.

I found the answer here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=16013

For those who may run into this issue in the future, the command you want to run is:

```
usermod -a -G gpio mysql
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your solution as an answer and accept it by clicking the chekmark next to it so both the question and answer can be more clear for those who may run into this issue in the future. Otherwise great question and solution!

Comment: Thank! I have posted the solution as a comment and marked it as the answer! Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect. Upvoted both of them, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Answer,

So the issue was caused by the mysql user not having permissions to use the GPIO pins. I resolved this by adding the mysql user to the gpio user group.

I found the answer here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=16013

For those who may run into this issue in the future, the command you want to run is:

```
usermod -a -G gpio mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know what could be going on with your specific setup (are you running Raspbian?  Python 2 or 3?  Etc.) but one thing to check is user permissions.  If I recall correctly, in Raspbian default settings, only root can access the GPIO pins; if you're running Python as root but your MySQL process is running without root privileges, that could explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am currently running Raspberry Pi 3. I did have a feeling this could be a permissions based issue. I'll have a look into running MySQL with root privileges and come back with the results! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Maxander, I have now solved this issue and edited the post to reflect this.